# Markov chain, confused items in the definition

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, markov-chains, markov-process

I do not understand this sentence about Markov chains (**search for the definitions of the notions as given at the end of the question**):

> In either case (homogeneous or non-homogeneous) the stochastic process may, or may not, be stationary. If it is stationary, its evolution may change over time (non-homogeneous) but
>   this evolution will be the same irrespective of when the process was initiated.

**How** is it possible that "it may change over time but this evolution will be the same",how can both conditions hold at the same time??

I.e. what is an example of a **Markov process** ,such that for all $\alpha$,
and for all $n$ and all $t_i$ and $x_i$ with $i = 1, 2,..., n$:
$$\mathrm{Prob}\{X(t_1) ≤ x_1, X(t_2) ≤ x_2,...,X(t_n) ≤ x_n\}=$$
$$\mathrm{Prob}\{X(t_1 + α) ≤ x_1, X(t_2 + α) ≤ x_2,..., X(t_n + α) ≤ x_n\}?$$

**Type this whole sentence ending with 194 (to find appropriate page number):**

"If it is stationary, its evolution may change over time (nonhomogeneous) but this evolution will be the same irrespective of when the process was initiated" 194

into google.

Comment: Strictly irrelevant to this question, but for the sake of clarification to others who might be confused, there is a different use of "stationary markov chain" that treats it as a synonym for "homogeneous markov chain".   The current [Wikipedia page for 'Markov chain'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Variations) says "Time-homogeneous Markov chains (or stationary Markov chains) are processes where $Pr(X_{n+1}=x|X_n=y) = Pr(X_n = x|X_{n-1}=y)$ for all $n$."  That's an obvious way of definining "homogenous" for Markov chains, in the sense that I understood the term here.

Answer (score 0):

It is a somewhat confusing passage.  The general intent, I think, is that the dynamic *rules* of the system (e.g., the transition rates) may change over time—that is, it is non-homogeneous—but if the system happens to be stationary at the present time, it doesn't matter whether it was started just now, or at some time in the distant past.  The equilibrium solution will progress the same way in either case.

Comment: Do you have some example that would illustrate the difference between homogeneous and stationary? It seems to me that stationary is strong enough to imply homogeneous but the authors claim that **all 4** combinations are possible:(non-)homogeneous and (non-)stationary. So what can be an example of MP which is non-homogeneous but stationary?

Comment: @user122424: Well, certainly a *degenerate* example is one in which the system is always in state $0$ before time $t_0$, and always in state $1$ after time $t_0$; it is clearly non-homogeneous, but (except at $t_0$) it is stationary as well.  Let me think about non-degenerate cases.

Comment: Ok. But can you think about (even degenerate) example, which is stationary at **all** states but non-homogeneous?